# Generate random number with given probability matlab

Tags: matlab, math, random, probability

I want to generate a random number with a given probability but I'm not sure how to:

I need a number between 1 and 3

```
num = ceil(rand*3);
```

but I need different values to have different probabilities of generating eg.

```
0.5 chance of 1
0.1 chance of 2
0.4 chance of 3
```

I'm sure this is straightforward but I can't think of how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw random numbers from pre-specified probability mass function in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607156/draw-random-numbers-from-pre-specified-probability-mass-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The simple solution is to generate a number with a uniform distribution (using [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)), and manipulate it a bit:

```
r = rand;
prob = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4];
x = sum(r >= cumsum([0, prob]));
```

or in a one-liner:

```
x = sum(rand >= cumsum([0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4]));
```

#### Explanation

Here `r` is a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1. To generate an integer number between 1 and 3, the trick is to divide the [0, 1] range into 3 segments, where the length of each segment is proportional to its corresponding probability. In your case, you would have:

- Segment [0, 0.5), corresponding to number 1.
- Segment [0.5, 0.6), corresponding to number 2.
- Segment [0.6, 1], corresponding to number 3.

The probability of `r` falling within any of the segments is proportional to the probabilities you want for each number. `sum(r >= cumsum([0, prob]))` is just a fancy way of mapping an integer number to one of the segments.

#### Extension

If you're interested in creating a vector/matrix of random numbers, you can use a loop or [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
r = rand(3); % # Any size you want
x = arrayfun(@(z)sum(z >= cumsum([0, prob])), r);
```

Of course, there's also a vectorized solution, I'm just too lazy to write it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there something I can do when the probabilities are [0,0,1] in this case I need the answer to be 3, but keep getting 1 ?

Comment: PS: You forgot to add the 0 on this line -> x = sum(rand >= cumsum([0.5, 0.1, 0.4));

Comment: Vectorized solution: `sum(bsxfun(@ge, r, cumsum([0, prob]),2)` where `r` is a column vector and `prob` a row vector.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Thanks for the vectorized solution ;)

Answer (score 9):

The answers so far are correct, but slow for large inputs: O(m*n) where n is the number of values and m is the number of random samples. Here is a O(m*log(n)) version that takes advantage of monotonicity of the `cumsum` result and the binary search used in `histc`:

```
% assume n = numel(prob) is large and sum(prob) == 1
r = rand(m,1);
[~,x] = histc(r,cumsum([0,prob]));
```

Comment: Small note, depending on how `histc` is implemented this could be O(n+m*log(n)). Though I'd hope since the first output is not used, this isn't the case.

Comment: There's an even better O(n + m) solution using the [Alias Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method). I've implemented it in the [sample_discrete.m](https://github.com/alecjacobson/gptoolbox/blob/master/matrix/sample_discrete.m) function.

Comment: The link is broken, fyi.

Answer (score 5):

```
>> c = cumsum([0.5, 0.1, 0.4]);
>> r = rand(1e5, 1);
>> x = arrayfun(@(x) find(x <= c, 1, 'first'), r);
>> h = hist(x, 1:3)

h =

       49953       10047       40000
```

`x` distributed as desired.

Comment: @EitanT, I don't think that `sum()` is faster than `find(..., 'first')`. Also, there is no need in adding zero. Please test it. In general case I would only add: `assert(c(end) == 1);`

Comment: Now that I think about it, my comment is out of place. My apologies.

Answer (score 5):

using `randsample` function from *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox*, you can generate random numbers with specified probability mass function (pmf):

```
pmf = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4];
population = 1:3;
sample_size = 1;

random_number = randsample(population,sample_size,true,pmf);
```

I think this is the easiest method.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more general solution would be:

```
r=rand;
prob=[.5,.1,.4];
prob=cumsum(prob);
value=[1,2,3];    %values corresponding to the probabilities
ind=find(r<=prob,1,'first');
x=value(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the probabilities are nice numbers like this it is possible to do a very simple and performant selection. We repeat population elements such that a uniform selection yields the desired probability distribution. In this case we create a population of 10, with 5 times 1 (0.5 probability of being selected), etc.

```
p = [1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3];
x = p(randi(numel(p));
```

`randi` takes a second input argument that determines the size of the output (the default is 1), so it’s simple to generate many values from this distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A vector solution using `rand`, `cumsum`, and `min`.

```
r = rand(10,1);
p = [0.5 0.1 0.4];
[~, ind] = min(r >= cumsum(p), [], 2)
```

- Randomly sample `r` from 0..1 using `rand`. In this case I put my data into a column vector.
- Put the probabilities for each output index into `p`.
- `r >= cumsum(p)` compares every combination of `r` and the cumulative probabilities of `p`. In this case the result is a 2D matrix where each row begins with a series of 1s and ends with a series of 0s. The first 0 indicates the element of `p` that was randomly selected.
- `min` is performed for all rows and returns the column index of the first 0. The third input to `min` defines the dimension over which to calculate the minimum.

If you want to extend this to n dimensions of `r`: change the shape of `p` so that it extends into one more dimension than what `r` has, and give that dimension as `min`'s third input.

```
r = rand(3, 5, 7);
p = []; 
p(1,1,1,:) = [0.5 0.1 0.4];
[~, ind] = min(r >= cumsum(p), [], 4)
```