# How can I use MATLAB program to create a new column array with random arrangements of 1, 2 and 3?

Tags: matlab, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate random number with given probability matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab)

I need to create a column vector with random assignments of the number 1, 2 and 3. However i need to be able to control the percentage occurrence of each oif these 3 numbers.

**For example**, i have a `100 x 1` column vector and I want 30 of the number 1, 50 of the number 2 and 20 of the number 3, in a random assignments.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether you can do that with `rand` or `randi` function.

May be you can write a small module something like this :

```
bit1 = 1 * ones(1,20);
bit2 = 2 * ones(1,50);
bit3 = 3 * ones(1,30);

bits = [bit1 bit2 bit3];
randbits = bits(:, randperm(length(bits)))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks... what if i need to run this randomisation 30 times. thus how do i create a 30x100 matrix which have 30 different random sequences instead of repeating the random commnand by 30 times. Sorry I am still quite new to MATLAB.

Comment: You have to use a loop in that conditional. Another way is to replace ones(1,20) with ones(30,20) maybe. Then you need to concatenate the array using `horzcat` or `vertcat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [CDF (cumulative destribution function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the percentage of each number.

```
pdf = [ 30 50 20 ]/100; % the prob. distribution fun. of the samples
cdf = cumsum( pdf );
% I assume here all entries of the PDF are positive and sum(pdf)==1
% If this is not the case, you may normalize pdf to sum to 1.
```

The sampling itself

```
n = 100; % number of samples required
v = rand(n,1); % uniformly samples
tmp = bsxfun( @le, v, cdf );
[~, r] = max( tmp, [], 2 );
```

As observed by @Dan (see comment below), last line can be replaced with

```
r = numel(pdf) + 1 - sum( tmp, 2 );
```

The vector `r` is a random vector of integers `1,2,3` and should satisfy the desired `pdf`

Comment: Is [~, r] = max( tmp, [], 2 ); the same as 4 - sum(tmp, 2) ?

Comment: @Dan - indeed! nice one...

Comment: thanks, just checking I understood as don't have matlab on me. This is a great solution btw.