# Draw random numbers from pre-specified probability mass function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, probability-theory

I have a support (`supp_epsilon`) and a probability mass function (`pr_mass_epsilon`) in Matlab, constructed as follows.

```
supp_epsilon=[0.005 0.01 0.015 0.02]; 

suppsize_epsilon=size(supp_epsilon,2);

pr_mass_epsilon=zeros(suppsize_epsilon,1);

alpha=1;
beta=4;

for j=1:suppsize_epsilon
    pr_mass_epsilon(j)=betacdf(supp_epsilon(j),alpha,beta)/sum(betacdf(supp_epsilon,alpha,beta));
end
```

Note that the components of `pr_mass_epsilon` sum up to `1`. Now, I want to draw `n` random numbers from `pr_mass_epsilon`. How can I do this? I would like a code that works for any `suppsize_epsilon`.

In other words: I want to randomly draw elements from `supp_epsilon`, each element with a probability given by `pr_mass_epsilon`.

Comment: Related question on vectorization of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58631801/8239061

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using the Statistics Toolbox

The [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) function can do that directly:

```
result = randsample(supp_epsilon, n, true, pr_mass_epsilon);
```

## Without using toolboxes

Manual approach:

1. Generate `n` samples of a uniform random variable in the interval (0,1).
2. Compare each sample with the distribution function (cumulative sum of mass function).
3. See in which interval of the distribution function each uniform sample lies.
4. Index into the array of possible values

```
result = supp_epsilon(sum(rand(1,n)>cumsum(pr_mass_epsilon(:)), 1)+1);
```

---

For your example, with `n=1e6` either of the two approaches gives a histogram similar to this:

```
histogram(result, 'normalization', 'probability')
```

[image]

Comment: Both the answers here (with & without toolboxes) are superior to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33015000/8239061) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13914066/8239061) both in simplicity and accessibility.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Good find. Do you think this should be marked as a duplicate of the second one you linked? The only difference is the population of values

Comment: I flagged both of those as duplicates of this one (this really should be the target) as they both deal with generating discrete random variables from a probability mass function. So no, my opinion is they should be dupes of this one.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted a related question for vectors now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631801/vector-version-of-randsample-in-matlab