# How do I generate random numbers in such range?

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate some random numbers, that is for such distribution:

- 10% of them are in Category A (T = 6),
- 40% of them are in Category B (T = 8),
- 40% of them are in Category C (T = 10),
- 10% of them are in Category D (T = 12).

I just started to learn MATLAB and I tried `rand(x)` and `randn(x)` but it seems neither of them can do that?

Comment: I believe the linked question is a duplicate, with a variety of solutions for your problem. Please say why if you believe this isn't the case.

Comment: I think [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58607156/8239061) provides a superior answer from @LuisMendo than the [currently linked dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13914066/8239061).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: added that dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set up some kind of mapping from the uniformly distributed random numbers you get from [`rand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) to your desired values, i.e. with respect to the wanted distribution.

In my solution, I generate random numbers using `rand`, and map them to integers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` as well as to (categorical) characters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. I built a whole function to support variable amount of input arguments to mimic the behaviour of `rand`.

That's the code of the `myRand` function:

```matlab
function [rn, in, ch] = myRand(varargin)

  % No input arguments.
  if (numel(varargin) == 0)  
    rn = rand();

  % One input argument; might be a scalar or an array.
  elseif (numel(varargin) == 1)
    a = varargin{1};
    if (!isnumeric(a))
      error('myRand: argument must be numeric');
    end
    rn = rand(a);

  % More than one input argument; must be scalars.
  elseif (numel(varargin) > 1)
    if (!all(cellfun(@(x)isnumeric(x), varargin)))
      error('myRand: arguments must be numeric');  
    end
    if (!all(cellfun(@(x)isscalar(x), varargin)))
      error('myRand: arguments must be scalar');  
    end
    rn = rand(varargin{:});

  end

  in = zeros(size(rn));
  in((0 <= rn) & (rn < 0.1)) = 1;
  in((0.1 <= rn) & (rn < 0.5)) = 2;
  in((0.5 <= rn) & (rn < 0.9)) = 3;
  in((0.9 <= rn) & (rn < 1)) = 4;

  ch = cell(size(rn));  
  ch((0 <= rn) & (rn < 0.1)) = { 'A' };
  ch((0.1 <= rn) & (rn < 0.5)) = { 'B' };
  ch((0.5 <= rn) & (rn < 0.9)) = { 'C' };
  ch((0.9 <= rn) & (rn < 1)) = { 'D' };

end
```

And, here's some test code with the corresponding outputs:

```matlab
% Single random number with integer and category
[rn, in, ch] = myRand()

% Multiple random numbers with integers and categories (array input)
[rn, in, ch] = myRand([2, 3])

% Multiple random numbers with integers and categories (multiple scalars input)
[rn, in, ch] = myRand(2, 3)


rn =  0.19904
in =  2
ch =
{
  [1,1] = B
}

rn =
   0.206294   0.420426   0.835194
   0.793874   0.593371   0.034055

in =
   2   2   3
   3   3   1

ch =
{
  [1,1] = B
  [2,1] = C
  [1,2] = B
  [2,2] = C
  [1,3] = C
  [2,3] = A
}

rn =
   0.96223   0.87840   0.49925
   0.54890   0.88436   0.92096

in =
   4   3   2
   3   3   4

ch =
{
  [1,1] = D
  [2,1] = C
  [1,2] = C
  [2,2] = C
  [1,3] = B
  [2,3] = D
}
```

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer: I tested the code with Octave 5.1.0, but I'm quite sure, that it should be fully MATLAB-compatible. If not, please leave a comment, and I'll try to fix possible issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it in MATLAB, and error happened in line 'ch((0 <= rn) & (rn < 0.1)) = 'A';' saying that Conversion to cell from char is not possible.

Comment: @Bobet I edited my answer, please try again. The characters are now explicitly put into a cell.