# Random number with user-defined distribution function (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, random

Is there a way one could get the random number generation satisfying a user-determined distribution function. In MATLAB, I have found random number generators with uniform and normal distribution functions only.

Comment: How would you want to specify this "user-determined distribution function"? Also discrete or continuous?

Comment: And have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab

Comment: Dan, your last comment is usefull

Answer (score 3):

The [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/index.html) has a large number of random number generators with predefined distributions. Hopefully the ones you need are contained in the list:

> ```
> Random Number Generators.
>
>   betarnd     - Beta random numbers.
>   binornd     - Binomial random numbers.
>   chi2rnd     - Chi square random numbers.
>   evrnd       - Extreme value random numbers.
>   exprnd      - Exponential random numbers.
>   frnd        - F random numbers.
>   gamrnd      - Gamma random numbers.
>   geornd      - Geometric random numbers.
>   gevrnd      - Generalized extreme value random numbers.
>   gprnd       - Generalized Pareto inverse random numbers.
>   hygernd     - Hypergeometric random numbers.
>   iwishrnd    - Inverse Wishart random matrix.
>   johnsrnd    - Random numbers from the Johnson system of distributions.
>   lognrnd     - Lognormal random numbers.
>   mhsample    - Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.
>   mnrnd       - Multinomial random vectors.
>   mvnrnd      - Multivariate normal random vectors.
>   mvtrnd      - Multivariate t random vectors.
>   nbinrnd     - Negative binomial random numbers.
>   ncfrnd      - Noncentral F random numbers.
>   nctrnd      - Noncentral t random numbers.
>   ncx2rnd     - Noncentral Chi-square random numbers.
>   normrnd     - Normal (Gaussian) random numbers.
>   pearsrnd    - Random numbers from the Pearson system of distributions.
>   poissrnd    - Poisson random numbers.
>   randg       - Gamma random numbers (unit scale).
>   random      - Random numbers from specified distribution.
>   randsample  - Random sample from finite population.
>   raylrnd     - Rayleigh random numbers.
>   slicesample - Slice sampling method.
>   trnd        - T random numbers.
>   unidrnd     - Discrete uniform random numbers.
>   unifrnd     - Uniform random numbers.
>   wblrnd      - Weibull random numbers.
>   wishrnd     - Wishart random matrix.
> ```

You could also use [`random`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/random.html), which basically calls one of the above functions depending of the name of the distribution:

> ```
> RANDOM Generate random arrays from a specified distribution.
>
>   R = RANDOM(NAME,A) returns an array of random numbers chosen from the
>   one-parameter probability distribution specified by NAME with parameter
>   values A.
>
>   [...]
>
>   NAME can be:
>
>     'beta'  or 'Beta',
>     'bino'  or 'Binomial',
>     'chi2'  or 'Chisquare',
>     'exp'   or 'Exponential',
>     'ev'    or 'Extreme Value',
>     'f'     or 'F',
>     'gam'   or 'Gamma',
>     'gev'   or 'Generalized Extreme Value',
>     'gp'    or 'Generalized Pareto',
>     'geo'   or 'Geometric',
>     'hyge'  or 'Hypergeometric',
>     'logn'  or 'Lognormal',
>     'nbin'  or 'Negative Binomial',
>     'ncf'   or 'Noncentral F',
>     'nct'   or 'Noncentral t',
>     'ncx2'  or 'Noncentral Chi-square',
>     'norm'  or 'Normal',
>     'poiss' or 'Poisson',
>     'rayl'  or 'Rayleigh',
>     't'     or 'T',
>     'unif'  or 'Uniform',
>     'unid'  or 'Discrete Uniform',
>     'wbl'   or 'Weibull'.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) with weighted seampling. Suppose you want to sample `k` numbers in range `1:n` with probability `p` (where `p` is a non-negative vector of length `n`) then

```
randsample( n, k, true, p );
```

Comment: +1 But this is valid only for _discrete_ distributions with a _finite_ number of possible values