# How to generate random numbers with given probability and constraints?

Tags: matlab

N.B: This is not a duplication of my last question because I added constraints!

I want to generate a matrix A(40x10000) of random number between 1 and 100 with a given probability:

```
p1=Prob(1)     (chance of 1)
p2=Prob(2)     (chance of 2)
 ... 
p100=Prob(100)  (chance of 100)
```

and constraints: V1,V2,...,V20 are vectors containing 4 elements between 1 and 100. Each column vector of the matrix A should contain at least one element of each of these 20 vectors. `V1, ..., V20` are predefined vectors with known elements.

for example, how to modify the following program to add the last constraint:

```
h = 40; w = 10000;
A = reshape( randsample( numel(Prob), h*w, true, Prob ), [h w] );
```

more details:

- each `A(:,i)` `{i=1,..,10000}` should contain `Vk(1) or Vk(2) or Vk(3) or Vk(4)` for all `k=1,..,20`.  `A(:,i)` must contain at least one value from every `Vk`, but that it will respect the probabilities and does not generate duplicate values. If some values of `Vi` and `Vj` are equal, `A(:,k)` could have a single element validating both `Vi` and `Vj` constraints.
- for example: if `V1=[6 87 1 56]`, `A(:,i)` should contain 6 or 87 or 1 or 56 but `A(:, i)` may contain (6 and 1) or (6 and 1 and 87) or ...

Comment: could you show us a small example, I'm not sure I understand the constraints..

Comment: @Amro: each A(:,i) (i=1,..,10000) should contain Vk(1) or Vk(2) or Vk(3) or Vk(4) for all k=1,..,20

Comment: @Amro: if V1=[6 87 1 56], A(:,i) should contain 6 or 87 or 1 or 56 but A (:, i) may contain (6 and 1) or (6 and 1 and 87) or ...

Comment: and how are the vectors `V1,V2,..` generated exactly? Also must a column `A(:,i)` use at least one value from *every* `Vk`? It would be better to edit the question and add all these details..

Comment: @Amro: V1, ..., V20 are predefined vectors with known elements

Comment: ok. how about you generate `A` just like before, and then simply overwrite the first value of each column by choosing one value at random from a `Vk` to ensure at least one element is picked from those 20 vectors. That would satisfy the constraints, right?

Comment: @Amro: yes, A(:,i) must use at least one value from every Vk.

Comment: @Amro: but that it will respect the probabilities and does not generate duplicate values?

Comment: @bzak the solution by Amro is really good and it takes very less time. I am removing my solution.

Comment: @Naveen: time is not a problem for me, I can wait 4 min. The important thing is to have the right Result!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not getting it... Perhaps others will be able to provide you help.

Comment: @bzak then try my solution and see if you are able to get the expected results.

Comment: @user1735003: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
h=40;
w=10000;
output=zeros(h,w);
i=1;
while i<=w
temp=randsample(numel(prob),h,true,prob);
check=all(any(ismember(vec,temp)));
if check~=0
output(:,i)=temp;
i=i+1;
end
end
```

**Unfortunately, this takes approximately 4 minutes to generate the matrix with the specified constraints.** Any other solution which takes less time is welcome.

Comment: What is vec in your answer?

Comment: @bzak `vec` is the matrix containing the constraint vectors. I had taken it as a `4 X 20` matrix.

Comment: this solution gives exactly what I want, but the program execution time rises exponentially when I increase the size of vec. For example: if vec is a 8 x 100 matrix and h=50, P.E.T=30 hours !!!

Comment: This algorithm is inaccurate. It does not generate solutions which reflect the probabilities passed in `prob` because the likelyhood of rejecting a solution is lower if it contains many rare(low `prob`) numbers.

Comment: I agree that the algorithm is not inaccurate. I also think that it is nontrivial to improve it and in many applications this is a reasonable approach ... the user should be careful to understand the solution and decide for him or herself whether or not this "sample and reject if it doesn't meet constraints" idea works for their application.