# Custom histogram density evaluation in MatLab

Tags: matlab, histogram, kernel-density

Does MatLab have any built in function to evaluate the density of a random variable from a custom histogram? (I suspect there are probably lots of ways to do this, I am just looking to see if there is already any builtin MatLab functionality).
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random number with given probability matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab)

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate density"? `hist`? `histc`? `ksdensity`?

Comment: Say that my histogram is a discretized version of a continuous density. How can I evaluate f(x) from the histogram?

Comment: The histogram _is_ an estimation of the probability density. You only need to normalize, dividing by {sample size times bin width}, so that the area is 1. Then, if you need to evaluate the probability density at intermediate values, use interpolation

Comment: Yes, any quick way to this interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`hist`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) gives you an approximation of the probability density you are evaluating.

If you want a continuous representation of it, [this article from the Matlab documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/smoothing-a-histogram.html) explains how to get one using the `spline` command from the Curve Fitting Toolbox. Basically the article explains how to make a cubic interpolation of your histogram.

The resulting code is :

```
y = randn(1,5001); % Replace y by your own dataset

[heights,centers] = hist(y);
hold on
n = length(centers);
w = centers(2)-centers(1);
t = linspace(centers(1)-w/2,centers(end)+w/2,n+1);
dt = diff(t);
Fvals = cumsum([0,heights.*dt]);
F = spline(t, [0, Fvals, 0]);
DF = fnder(F);
hold on
fnplt(DF, 'r', 2)
hold off
ylims = ylim;
ylim([0,ylims(2)]);
```

[image: Continuous representation of Gaussian density]

Answer (score 0):

A popular way is to use kernel density estimation. The simplest way to do this in Matlab is using [`ksdensity`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html).