# Generate random number with given probability

Tags: r, matlab, random, vector

I have a question which is basically the vectorized R solution to the following matlab problem:

[Generate random number with given probability matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab)

I'm able to generate the random event outcome based on random uniform number and the given probability for each single event (summing to 100% - only one event may happen) by:

```
sum(runif(1,0,1) >= cumsum(wdOff))
```

However the function only takes a single random uniform number, whereas I want it to take a vector of random uniform numbers and output the corresponding events for these entries.

So basically I'm looking for the R solution to Oleg's vectorized solution in matlab (from the comments to the matlab solution):

"Vectorized solution: `sum(bsxfun(@ge, r, cumsum([0, prob]),2)` where `r` is a column vector and `prob` a row vector. –  Oleg"

Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: if you did want to do this without `sample()` you could probably use `findInterval()` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw random numbers from pre-specified probability mass function in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607156/draw-random-numbers-from-pre-specified-probability-mass-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could just do a weighted random sample, without worrying about your cumsum method:

```
sample(c(1, 2, 3), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.4))
```

If you already have the numbers, you could also do:

```
x <- runif(10, 0, 1)
as.numeric(cut(x, breaks = c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 1)))
```

Comment: @SophusBonnenRossen If Jeremycg's answer helped you please mark it as correct answer!