# Generate matrix based on density function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to generate a `2`-by-`6` matrix of random numbers based on their density function, for example

f(x)= 2x-4 for 2 <  x < 3; 0 otherwise

So from what I understand I have to find the cumulative density function first, x<sup>2</sup>-4x, and then I have to invert it so that I can use the rand function.

This is that part I do not understand, how do I get the inverted function

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13914141/1011724.

However, your PDF is continuous so you need to adjust it slightly. The `cumsum` part becomes your CDF and the `sum(r >= ...` part becomes a definite integral from `0` to `rand` (which is just your CDF since it evaluates to `0` at `x==0`) so  (ignoring your limits) you get

```
X = @(x)x.^2 - 4x
```

To generate a random matrix go `X(rand(2,6))`

To account for your limits you can just multiply the entire function by `x > 2 & x < 3` but also if it's greater than `3` then although the PDF is `0`, the CDF should still be 3<sup>2</sup> - 4 =5

```
X_limited = @(x)(x.^2 - 4x ).*(x > 2 & x < 3) + (x>=3)*5
```

If you plot a graph of `(x > 2 & x < 3)` you will see it is a rectangular function between `2` and `3` and so multiplying by it makes anything outside of that window `0` but leaves anything inside the window unchanged. Similarly, `x >= 3` is a step function start at `x == 3` and thus it adds `5` to any values higher than `3` and since the windowing function will make sure the first term is zero when `x` is greater then `3`, this step function ensures a value of `5` for all `x` greater than `3`.

Now you just need to generate random numbers in whatever your range is. Assuming it's between `0` and `5`

```
x = rand(2,6)*5
X_limited(x)
```