# Stuck in implementing a method for mapping symbols to an interval - if-else loop not working properly implementation does not match theory

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying out an encoding - decoding method that had been asked in this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820958/matlab-help-in-implementing-a-mathematical-equation-for-generating-multi-level

and a related one [Generate random number with given probability matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There are 2 parts to this question - encoding and decoding. Encoding of a symbolic sequence is done using inverse interval mapping using the map `f_inv`. The method of inverse interval mapping yields a real valued number. Based on the real valued number, we iterate the map `f()`. The solution in the post in the first link does not work - because once the final interval is found, the iteration of the map `f()` using the proposed solution does not yield the same exact symbolic array. So, I tried by directly implementing the equations for the forward iteration `f()` given in the paper for the decoding process, but the decoding does not generate the same symbolic sequence.

Here is a breif explanation of the problem.

Let there be an array `b = [1,3,2,6,1]` containing `N = 5` integer valued elements with probability of occurence of each unique integer as `0.4,    0.2,    0.2,    0.2` respectively. The array `b` can take any integers from the unique symbol set `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`. Let `n = 8` elements in the symbol set. In essence, the probability for the above data `b` is 
`p= [ 0.4 (for symbol 1),   0.2 (for symbol 2) ,    0.2 (symbol 3), 0 (for symbol 4 not occuring),  0 (for symbol 5),   0.2(for symbol 6),  0 (for symbol 7), 0 (for symbol 8)]`

An interval `[0,1]` is split into 8 regions. Let, the interval for the data `b` assumed to be known as
   `Interval_b = [0,   0.4,    0.6,    0.8,    1];`

In general, for `n = 8` unique symbols, there are  `n = 8` intervals such as `I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4, I_5, I_6, I_6,I_7,I_8` and each of these intervals is assigned a symbol such as `[    1   2   3   4   5  6   7 8]`

Let, `x = 0.2848` that has been obtained from the reverse interval mapping for the symbol array  `b` from the solution for the encoding procedure in the link. There is a mapping rule which maps `x` to the symbol depending on the interval in which `x` lies and we should obtain the same symbol elements as in `b`. The rule is

Comment: It is helpful if your provide a reference/ screenshot of the paper/book that you have taken the formula from

Comment: @rahnema1: I have updated the question and put the link based on which I have asked this question.

Comment: I have provided an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40821660/6579744) to that question that were about `piecewise linear chaotic map`

Comment: I see, I did not notice your name. I have used the first part of the problem which is to find the initial condition from the reverse interval mapping. variable `sigma` I think contains the intervals. But, the forward iteration using the initial condition does not give the exact symbolic sequence. Hence, this question. I am interested in that approach of reverse interval mapping, but you can see in this question that if I apply the forward map `f()` the sequence is not correct. Can you please take a look in this question why the decoding is not working?

Comment: From the decoding procedure in your approach, it is not clear how the forward iterations are getting mapped to probability and hence the interval to get the symbols. I checked your decoding part, but the decoded symbols are not correct, the code gives `1     3     2     3     4`
instead of `1,3,2,6,1` for the intitial condtion `x=0.2848`

Comment: The initial condition for the string `b = [1,3,2,6,1]` obtained using your code for inverse interval mapping `f_inv()` yields `x = 0.2848`. The decoding starts using this `x` and the equation and intervals for `f()`.   I shall really appreciate if you can tell me why the decoding is not working based on your solution in the link
 
 
I implemented the equation for the function `f()` as given in the paper under the function `ObtainSymbols()`. But,  the decoded symbols are not correct, the initial condition gives the symbols `1 3 2 3 4` instead of `1,3,2,6,1`

Comment: I will update the answer .`X = Reduced_interval(1);` should be changed to `X = mean(Reduced_interval);`

Comment: @rahnema1:Can you please see the update in this question. Even after your correction, the solution does not work.

Comment: for input `b=[1 3 2 6 1]` `result = uniqueSym(ii);`  produces the same symbol

Comment: If using `` X = (X - Interval(ii(k))) ./ p(ii(k));` is equivalent to the implementation of the forward iteration map `f()`, then it must be possible to use the full functional form of the equation `f()` rather than this vectorized version to produce the same sequence as you say using `result = uniqueSym(ii)`. I don't wan't a vectorized version but want to apply the function `f()` as I have shown under `ObtainSymbols()` using the initial contion `X = Reduced_interval(1)`. Can you  please help how I can mitigate the error and iterate the map using this `X` and not by the vectorized method

Comment: It will be immensely helpful if you could provide the code for step by step implementation of the maps `f()` and `f_inv()` in a non-vectorized way. In the current implementation, it is not possible to apply the intervals to iterate using the functional form of the map `f()`. This approach is theoretically not correct.

Comment: I have implemented the non-vectorized version of the function `f()` and would really really appreciate your help in the non-vectorized version (not using the `f_inv = @(I, idxsymbol) Interval(idxsymbol) + p(idxsymbol) * I;
`) of `f_inv()` function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the argument `Interval` passed to function `ObtainSymbols` should contain entries for all elements, including the ones with probability 0. This can be done by adding the statement

```
Interval = cumsum([0, p_arr]);
```

immediately before the calls to function `ObtainSymbols`.

The following is the output with this modificaiton:

```
...
p_arr = [p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6,p_7,p_8];
% unchanged script above this

% recompute Interval for all symbols
Interval = cumsum([0, p_arr]);
% [0   0.4   0.6   0.8   0.8   0.8   1.0   1.0   1.0]

% unchanged script below    
[y1,symbol1] = ObtainSymbols(x(1),p_arr,Interval);
[y2,symbol2] = ObtainSymbols(y1,p_arr,Interval);
[y3,symbol3] = ObtainSymbols(y2,p_arr,Interval);
[y4,symbol4] = ObtainSymbols(y3,p_arr,Interval);
[y5,symbol5] = ObtainSymbols(y4,p_arr,Interval);
Symbols = [symbol1,symbol2,symbol3,symbol4,symbol5]
y = [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]

% Symbols = [1     3     2     6     1]
% y = [0.7136    0.5680    0.8400    0.2000    0.5000]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, there is an error for array `b` other than the one used here. So, if I use your anwer then the values in `Symbols` array is different from the values in 'b`. I have put this as an update in the Question. Can you please see what is the problem

Comment: When the number of samples `N` increases from 5 to something else, the program does not give the same symbol sequence as in `b`. Moreover, Ineed to re-run the code several times to get the correct sequence even when `b` is fixed and not random. So, the result is not stable. In the Update, for  N = 20, I am getting all wrong symbol mapping :(

Comment: Looking at how you compute `p_1`, `p_2`, etc it seems that you expect the elements of `b` to be 1 or higher. So, of course, the code would fail if you have a 0 in `b`. Try testing with `b = randi([1 n],1,N);`, which ensures that every element of `b` is higher than zero.