# Select randomly from array with given probabilites without replacement

Tags: matlab, random, probability

Assume I have an array of items `[1,2, ...n]`, and a probabilities array `[p1,p2,....,pn]`, where `n` is a very large number and may reach to thousands.  The sum of all probabilities equals 1.

- I need to select 3 unique items randomly each time, an item with a high probability has a higher chance of being selected.
- I need to do the selection for more than 20k times.

I've implemented a working method by creating a new array that contains the items with repetition based on their probability. For example, if probabilities for item1, item2, and item3 are `[2/n,4/n,1/n]` respectively, then the new array will contain `[1,1,2,2,2,2,3]`.

It works fine but it's not efficient. Also, using this method there is the possibility of selecting the same item multiple times, then I have to reselect another item which consumes time.

Are there any efficient methods or built-in functions in MATLAB for this purpose?

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13914141/1011724

Comment: Also for the *pick without replacement* issue, if `n`is large and you're only picking 3 values, you probably just want to check for repetitions and repick if found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number with given probability matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab)

Comment: You _specify probabilities_ for the items, but you also want to sample _without replacement_. With those two requirements, it seems difficult to avoid re-picking. For example, [`randsample`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) can handle either requirement, but not both at the same time. Note also that in your current method, if sampled values are not unique you should start over and repick _all_ items, otherwise probabilities are not guaranteed

Comment: This is not a dupe of the linked Q&A, because of the no-replacement requirement here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial arrays

```
 x = [1, 2, 3];   % 1:n, where n = 3
 p = [2, 4, 1]/7; % probabilities of choosing each element
```

You can choose an element with given probability using this:

```
 r = rand; % get random number in range (0,1)
 xi = x(find(cumsum(p) >= r, 1)); % Get x where cumulative probability >= random number
```

You want to choose without replacement, so let's remove the element each loop

```
k = 2;           % number of choices
r = rand(k,1);   % random numbers
xi = zeros(k,1); % output choices
for ii = 1:k     % choices loop
    % Choose x with probability of each element contained in p
    idx = find(cumsum(p) >= r(ii), 1);
    xi(ii) = x(idx);
    % Remove item from lists
    x(idx) = []; p(idx) = [];
    % Rescale probabilities
    p = p/sum(p);
end
```

With this method, duplicate `x` entries will be treated as independent, with respect to their own specified `p` values.

Note: if you want to do this selection `N` times then use some temporary `x` and `p` variables, so that the next time you do the selection you haven't removed some elements! Or even better, vectorise the selection loop and make `x` and `p` into `N×n`, removing an element from each row each time.

Answer (score -1):

The function [`datasample`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) does what you ask for, if you use it with the optional argument `Weights` and then your weight array.

**Note:** `datasample` uses the old function `histc` to generate the sample, whereas the newer `histcounts` is recommended. Though this is only a problem if you want better efficiency. Quote from the documentation:

> histc is not recommended. Use HISTCOUNTS instead.